# Reference Local File in C# .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, epplus

We use EPPlus to build and export Excel files. In this scenario, we have a complex template that would be easier to fill in than build from scratch. Assuming we have two folders at the root of the .NET Core 6.0 project, "/Controllers" and "/Templates", I'd like to be able to reference the template from a controller in the "Controllers" folder using a relative path such as "../Templates/template.xlsx".

Comment: Controllers aren't in the "controllers folder". Source files get compiled into an assembly, and that assembly lives next to the Templates directory. So you don't need to "..".

Comment: I would suggest you could check this example. `app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions(){FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyStaticFiles")),RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")});` Ref: [Working with Static Files](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this from your controller. and it will reference the file wherever you deploy code. Not a relative path but still usable in controller code.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Templates\template.xlsx");
```

Of course make sure directory and file exist, but if its in code they it should.

Comment: His goal is to reference the file from the controller also too. This will achieve that. A relative path is not absolutely needed. Unless he specifies another reason this will work for him.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the path with IWebHostEnvironment. Inject it into your controller.. and..

```
string path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Templates");

string filename = "template.xlsx";

string fullfile = Path.Combine(path, filename);
```

be sure to check if the directory exists